# Issues when importing a project from different machine RFT

Tags: import, rft

I am trying to export a RFT project from a machine and run the scripts in different machine.
Most of the testing is GUI testing. But the script works in one machine and in the other machine it fails.

I have seen few other differences also , when the same test case is recorded the recorded script is different in both the machines.

on 1st machine :

```
startApp("KKKKK");
browser_htmlBrowser(document_tcsBNCS(),DEFAULT_FLAGS).inputKeys("{CAPSLOCK}username{TAB}");
browser_htmlBrowser(document_tcsBNCS(),DEFAULT_FLAGS).inputKeys("pwd@{Num9}{Num0}{Num9}{Num0}");
```

on 2nd machine :

```
startApp("KKKKK");
tcsBNCSMicrosoftInternetExplo().inputKeys("{CAPSLOCK}username{CAPSLOCK}{TAB}");
tcsBNCSMicrosoftInternetExplo().inputKeys("pwd@{Num9}{Num0}{Num9}{Num0}");
_Loginbutton().click(atPoint(16,6));
```

Versions of both RFT's are same. Why is the code generated different in diff machines? 
And how can i resolve these compatibility issues.

Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems on the second machine the browser is perhaps not enabled .
Could you verify the same by running the browser enablement test?